# bit-shift right-hand operand type

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm wondering what the correct right-hand operand is for C/C++ bit-shift operators.

At time of writing, the built-in arithmetic types are all less than 256 bits, so a single byte would be sufficient. Furthermore, x86 shift-instructions use `imm8`. Together this suggests the right-hand operand should be an `unsigned char` and use of a different type here will require type-conversion.

Is there a "most correct" type to use here? I know the standard is strangely lenient about other aspects of bit-shifting so maybe this is another case of the same?

Comment: For all intents and purposes the type is `int`.

Comment: FWIW, the C 11 expression grammar can be found here:  https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#A.2.1  Depending on the expression and how you count, a shift expression is about five to eight levels down from a top-level `primary-expression`.  And yes, there are a lot of paths that result in a `shift-expression`, so I'd say "lenient" is an accurate characterization of the syntax.

Comment: Re “Furthermore, x86 shift-instructions use `imm8`”: The machine instructions may influence a C implementation (as by the implementation’s choices of widths to use for the integer types), but they do not dictate it. A major purpose of using a compiler is to have it generate the instructions, and it will generate the instruction necessary to implement the C semantics, even if that means use multiple instructions to get the job done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any integer type can be used as the right operand of a bitwise shift, so long as the value is at least 0 and less than the bit length of the left operand.

This is spelled out in section 6.5.7 p2 and p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Bitwise Shift Operators:

> *2* Each of the operands shall have integer type
>
> *3* The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type
> of the result is that  of  the  promoted  left  operand. If  the
> value  of  the  right  operand  is  negative  or is greater than or
> equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is
> undefined.

So while the range of an `unsigned char` should be sufficient to hold any valid value, the right operand will be promoted to `int` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

C tends to want to do everything as at least `int`, so it would be very surprising if the RHS of `<<` and `>>` were to be specified as `unsigned short` or `unsigned char`.

It's hard to imagine why a programmer would ever use `long` (or, god help us, `long long`) there, but I just tried this code:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 16;
    long int y = 2;
    int z1 = x << y;
    int z2 = x >> y;
    printf("%d %d\n", z1, z2);

    long long int y2 = 2;
    z1 = x << y2;
    z2 = x >> y2;
    printf("%d %d\n", z1, z2);
}
```

I compiled it under two compilers, and neither gave any warnings, and both programs printed `64 4`.  (Not a conclusive test, but suggestive.)

Comment: Why enter an answer with hunches and inconclusive tests when we already have an answer citing an authoritative source, the C standard?

Comment: Why should it give you any warnings? It will if the compiler can predict the value of the right operand and this value will be negative or greater than the with of the left operand.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Because, sometimes, multiple perspectives on an answer can be useful, depending on the OP's needs, and I thought this might be one of those.  (Also, although empirical tests can be risky, I wanted to give the OP a gentle nudge that they might have tried one.)

Comment: @0___________ *If* there were anything wrong with using `long` or `long long` there, if there were any reason to discourage it, one might expect a high-quality compiler (I tried gcc and clang) to emit an error.  Since neither did, that suggests that, no, there's nothing wrong with using a right-hand operand wider than `int` for those operators.

Comment: Re “It's hard to imagine why a programmer would ever use `long`”: Because they have decoded various information stored in a `long`, e.g., `(x >> 23 & 0xFF)`, to get some bits out of it that they want to use as a shift amount, after which `e >> (x >> 23 & 0xFF)` has a `long` for the right operand simply because that is what it is after the operation on `x`.